# Google Analytics iPhone SDK (dispatchPeriod)

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

Greetings,
I've been wrestling with Google analytics for iPhone for a bit and I'm noticing the 10 second dispatchPeriod is being ignored. All the events I'm tracking are coming through just fine on the google analytics site however I believe the only the time the data is uploaded is when the app is restarted. I was hoping the dispatch schedule would take care of any queued up events.

I start my tracker like so:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSLog(@"App Delegate: applicationDidFinishLaunching");

    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-xxxxxxx-x"
                                           dispatchPeriod:10
                                                 delegate:self];

    NSError *error;

    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]
                                         action:@"launch"
                                          label:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]
                                          value:-1
                                      withError:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"GANTracker - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

    -(void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)eventsDispatched eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)eventsFailedDispatch
    {
       //The delegate method only gets called once at launch

        NSLog(@"Google Analytics: Events Dispatched = %i | Events Failed Dispatched = %i", eve

ntsDispatched, eventsFailedDispatch);
}
```

and I track events like so:

```
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"preview"
                                                 action:@"preview"
                                                  label:@"preview"
                                                  value:-1
                                              withError:&error]) {

              NSLog(@"GANTracker - %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Was an issue with calling the trackEvent method from a detached tread.